# How to fix shell script that works at the command line? Script uses `mv`, quotation marks, parameter expansion, and variables

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a set of files in a directory. Some of the filenames contain an eight-digit date, like so:

```
test_file_20220101.txt
...
test_file_20220110.txt
```

I want to use a shell script to rename them such that the dates have dashes, like so:

```
test_file_2022-01-01.txt
...
test_file_2022-01-10.txt
```

I have some shell code which works (mostly) fine at the command line (once `echo` is removed*):

```
for f in ./*; 
do suffix="${f##*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}"; 
number="${f%"$suffix"}"; 
number="${number##*[\!0-9]}"; 
year="${number:0:4}"; 
month="${number:4:2}"; 
day="${number:6:2}"; 
echo mv "$f" "${f/$number/$year-$month-$day}"; 
done
```

However, when I add `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, or `#!/bin/zsh` at the start, save it as a script (with execution permissions), and run the script, it doesn’t effect the filename change, and I get this in `stdout`:

`echo mv ./test_file_20220110 ./test_file_20220110`

* Remove echo changes nothing; the undesired results are the same with the shell script. I don’t believe echo is the problem.

I’ve also tried, without success: replacing all `”` with `’` or all `’` with `”` and removing all quotation marks. All combinations produce the same erroneous script output. The output of running the script with `set -v` added doesn’t help me, but it is:

```
+ for f in './*'
+ suffix=
+ number=./test_file_20220101
+ number=
+ year=
+ month=
+ day=
+ echo mv ./test_file_20220101 ./test_file_20220101
mv ./test_file_20220101 ./test_file_20220101
... [etc.]
```

Configuration:

- default shell:   `zsh`
- macOS 12.1 “Monterey”

---

Separately, and as an additional improvement, I’d like to fix the fact that some files which don’t have the expected eight-digit pattern end up being renamed to something like `--other_filename.txt`. I use the following command separately, after using the above command at the CLI, to fix this successfully.

```
for f in *; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f##--}"; done
```

It would be nice if this “cleanup” command could be in the same script as above as a last “cleanup” sweep.

Comment: Note that `;` is a command *separator*, not a command *terminator*.  Unquoted newlines are also command separators, so you don't need to end lines of your script with semicolons.

Comment: The backslash in `number="${number##*[\!0-9]}"` shouldn't be there.

Comment: You coulld use `rename` command for this: `rename 's/(20\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).txt/$1-$2-$3.txt/' test_file_*`

Comment: @f-hauri Thanks, but `rename` is not available for macOS, only (I believe) linux. So I stick to `mv` so my script is (hopefully) platform agnostic.

Comment: @TransferOrbit, `!` as a negation character in a bracket expression is POSIX-compliant.  POSIX explicitly disclaims any specification for the meaning of a bracket expressions whose contents start with an unescaped `^`.  Some shells accept it as an alternative negation character, but that's an extension to the POSIX shell language.

Comment: @pjh Removing the `\ ` appears to fix it, thanks! Fwiw, both `[!0-9]` and `[^0-9]` appear to work, although [grymoire.com](http://grymoire.com) doesn’t elucidate what effects the difference might produce.

Comment: @F.Hauri, `rename` is problematic in general because there are two completely different versions of it and there are many systems were neither of them is installed.  See [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/264812).

Comment: _which works (mostly) fine at the command line _ : What do you mean by _mostly_ and what shell are you using on the command line?

Comment: @user1934428 For the case described here it works always. By _mostly_ I meant that it sometimes doesn’t work when, eg.: I alter the code to include sub-/parallel-directories `**/*`, or there is more than one string of eight digits in the filename. — I’m using `zsh`, which is also the default shell in my case.

Comment: In this case, add a concrete example where your code produces an unexpected result. I also suggest to add a `echo shell version is $ZSH_VERSION` on top of your script, so that we see which zsh is actually used to **run** the script (it's likely, not necessarily, the same which you are using on the command line).

Comment: The core of the problem is solved by the answer I accepted as long as I use the correct incantation of `!` or `\!` with the shell being used in the script. I learned numerous useful things here and don’t want to further call upon your generosity. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set -v` output may not help you, but it tells *me* that the script goes sideways when trying to extract the number from the filename.  In bash, at least, that's because you have quoted the `!` in your bracket expression.  That is, `[\!0-9]` matches one character from the set '!', '0', '1', ... '9', which is not what you want.

You should observe the same at the command line, and if you don't, then I cannot explain that.

This variation on your script works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*; do
  suffix=${f##*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
  number=${f%"$suffix"}
  number=${number##*[!0-9]}
  year=${number:0:4}
  month=${number:4:2}
  day=${number:6:2}
  echo mv "$f" "${f/${number}/${year}-${month}-${day}}"
done
```

(Changes other than the correction to the bracket expression are stylistic, not functional.)

Comment: [Also @pjh] There seems to be a difference in interpretation in script vs. CLI execution (or more probably `zsh` vs. `bash`/`sh`)...
At the _CLI_, I get:
- with `[!0-9]` I get `zsh: no such word in event`;
- with `[^0-9]` I get `mv ./tempfile_20220101.txt ./tempfile_2022-01-01.txt`;
- with `[\!0-9]` I also get `mv ./tempfile_20220101.txt ./tempfile_2022-01-01.txt`

Comment: [cont’d] Yet in a `bash` script (_with_ `echo` included): — with `[!0-9]` I get `mv ./tempfile_20220101.txt ./tempfile_2022-01-01.txt`; — with `[^0-9]` I also get `mv ./tempfile_20220101.txt ./tempfile_2022-01-01.txt`; — yet with `[\!0-9]` I get `mv ./tempfile_20220101.txt ./tempfile_20220101.txt`

Comment: @TransferOrbit, Bash interprets `[!0-9]` the same whether the shell is interactive or not.  You can test that for yourself by running Bash interactively in a terminal (just execute `/bin/bash` without arguments).

Answer (score 0):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates another way to do it:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

date_rx='([[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]])([[:digit:]][[:digit:]])([[:digit:]][[:digit:]])'
date_file_rx="(.*)${date_rx}(.*)"

for file in *; do
    if [[ $file =~ $date_file_rx ]]; then
        prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        year=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        month=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        day=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
        echo mv -n -v -- "$file" "${prefix}${year}-${month}-${day}${suffix}"
    fi
done
```